# Getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 while executing Hadoop Pragram on cloudera

Tags: java, hadoop, dictionary, reduce

on cloudera linux machine i am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3 .

I am unable to understand why this exception is coming for this program only others are orking fine for me.

public class TransactionCount extends Configured implements Tool {

```
@Override
public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {


    if(arg0.length<2)
    {
        System.out.println("Please provide inpt and output directory properly");
        return -1;
    }
    JobConf conf=new JobConf(com.ankur.MRpractice.TransactionCount.class); 

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(arg0[0]),new Path(arg0[1],new Path(arg0[2])));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(arg0[3]));

    conf.setMapperClass(TransMapper.class);
    conf.setReducerClass(TransReducer.class);

    conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    conf.setPartitionerClass(TransPartioner.class);
    conf.setNumReduceTasks(4);

    JobClient.runJob(conf);

    return 0;

}

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{
    int exitCode=ToolRunner.run(new TransactionCount(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}
```

}

Comment: **Command i am running is :**
hadoop jar TransactionCount.jar com.ankur.MRpractice.TransactionCount /user/mapreduce/tscInput/transactionCount /user/mapreduce/tscOutput

**which is :** hadoop jar jar_name Driver_Class input_file output_directory

**Getting Exception at line:** 
FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(arg0[0]),new Path(arg0[1],new Path(arg0[2])));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line,

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(arg0[0]),new Path(arg0[1],new Path(arg0[2])));

with

FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(arg0[0]),new Path(arg0[1]),new Path(arg0[2]));

And please try, I hope ,it will help, closing bracket of args1 is closing after arg2, which is creating problem.

Comment: Prashant still getting same exception even after correcting the error.

Comment: I am having same driver code for other class which is working fine.

public int run(String[] arg0) throws Exception {
  if(arg0.length<2)
  {System.out.println("Please provide inpt and output directory properly");return -1;
  }
  JobConf conf=new JobConf(com.ankur.practice.WordCount.class);   
  FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(arg0[0]),new Path(arg0[1]), new Path(arg0[2]));
  FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf,new Path(arg0[3]));

Comment: Have you rebuild jar after this modification? If yes, Please paste full exception, it will be more helpful to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at com.ankur.MRpractice.TransactionCount.run(TransactionCount.java:24)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
 at com.ankur.MRpractice.TransactionCount.main(TransactionCount.java:46)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) at

Comment: sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) at a.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:186)

Comment: If you are running your jar using the command that you mentioned in your question, then you are only passing 2 arguments which are input and output respectively, but as per your code, you have to pass 4 arguments after class name so, your command should be like,   **hadoop jar TransactionCount.jar com.ankur.MRpractice.TransactionCount /user/mapreduce/tscInput/transactionCount1 /user/mapreduce/tscInput/transactionCount2  /user/mapreduce/tscInput/transactionCount3 outputDirectory**

Answer (score 1):

I think in the if condition u should use **arg0.length<=3** instead of arg0.length<2. because u r using arg0[2] and arg0[3] also in your program which is third and forth argument respectively.

Comment: I tried but it is not working.
if i use your solution then i am getting message from if condition.